# prependTo content won't display until only after I resize the browser window in Chrome

Tags: jquery, append, squarespace

I am calling for some basic HTML and jQuery to be prependedTo an element once the page loads on my squarespace site. But nothing loads until I resize the browser window. I've searched all over for a similar issue and haven't been able to find much. One person suggested I trigger a 'resize' on page load but that didn't seem to work either

Here is the code I am using

```
<script> $(window).load(function() { $("<div id='container1'> <img src='http://www.kantoliving.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/PMX700-Profile.jpg' /> <img src='http://www.kantoliving.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/PMX700-Extends.jpg' /> </div>").prependTo( ".site-page" );}); </script>

<script>$(window).load(function(){
  $("#container1").twentytwenty();
});</script>
```

Here's the url to the page I'm testing this on: http://www.bernardodesigns.com/embed-test

Comment: Not sure what's actually causing the problem, but `$(window).trigger('resize')` should work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you're attaching the `twentytwenty` plugin immediately after you prepend the images, before they have a chance to load.  It appears the plugin requires you to wait until images have loaded before attaching the plugin.

Doing the prepend on document `ready` should fix the problem.  Doing so will cause the `load` event to wait for your new images to finish loading.

```
$(function() {
    $('...').prependTo('.site-page');
});
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#container1').twentytwenty();
});
```

(`$(function() { ... })` is a shortcut for `$(document).on('ready', function() { ... })`.)

Comment: Thank you Josh! Will give that a shot.